# 504 Gateway Time-out (Openresty)

Tags: ipfs, js-ipfs, ipfs-cli

i am trying to upload my website folder in ipfs. However when i try run it showing me 504 Gateway.

Can someone help me?
Thank you

[image: website uploaded in ipfs]

[image: When trying to access]

Comment: The `ipfs.io` gateway can't find the file in the DHT, try another gateway and make sure the node with the files pinned is reachable.

Comment: Hi sorry, try another gateway? how to do it? im quite new

Comment: and how will i make sure if the node with files pinned is reachable? cause i set pinning already in ipfs but still not working

Comment: @Smitop I encountered the same issue and tried IPFS its own and Pinata gateways, both timeout. The NFT platforms also had a hard time fetching the metadata files. Could that be a general issue?